# isEmpty Method for tictactoe game

Tags: java, loops, user-interface, methods, is-empty

```
public class TicTacToeModel {

    double xpos,ypos,xr,yr;
    char[][] position = {{' ',' ',' '},
                         {' ',' ',' '},
                         {' ',' ',' '}};

    /**
     * Turns row, col into the center of the cells of any screen of resolution h by w.
     * This is ideal for the view.
     */
    public void computePos(int row, int col, int h, int w){
        xpos=(col+0.5)*w/3.0;
        ypos=(row+0.5)*h/3.0;
        xr=w/8.0;
        yr=h/8.0;
    }
```

`isEmpty()` returns true if the cell at xpos ypos is blank. This does not validate that xpos and ypos are within range any idea how I can do this?

```
public boolean isEmpty(int xpos, int ypos){
    boolean isPosWithinRange = xpos>=0 && xpos<9 && ypos>=0 && ypos<9;
    return (position[xpos][ypos] == ' ' && isPosWithinRange);
}
```

Places an `O` at position xpos and ypos. No additional validation.

```
public void placeO(int xpos, int ypos) {
            if(isEmpty(xpos, ypos)) {
                position[xpos][ypos]='O';
        }

}
```

Comment: Why is `xpos`, `ypos`, etc are of `double` types? Why have you tested `xpos < 9`, even though it cannot be more than 2, considering `position` as an array of array?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should test that `xpos` and `ypos` are between 0-2:

```
boolean isPosWithinRange = xpos>=0 && xpos<3 && ypos>=0 && ypos<3;
```

Second, if they are not, you should not check the value of the cell, as it is an invalid one. use the [short circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) property of `&&`, by changing the order of the checks in the return statement:

```
return isPosWithinRange && position[xpos][ypos] == ' ';
```